# How to disable Remote Debugging in WKWebview?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview

By default , Remote debugging is enabled for WKWebView. I need to disable it due to security considerations. What is the best way to disable remote debugging in WKWebview?

I am loading my website URL into my app for particular feature.

Security issue is

****The application is vulnerable to manipulation of its web engine through the enabled remote debugging feature. This could lead to malicious JavaScript injections from the local applications and disclosure of sensitive information.**

There need to be activated the Web Inspector option and JavaScript (if not activated) on the device (Settings -> Safari -> Advanced). An attacker can connect to the device via Safari Develop menu (Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced -> "Show Develop menu in menu bar").**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/21521

Comment: What makes one way the best of all?  What does "There need to be activated the Web Inspector option and JavaScript (if not activated) on the device (Settings -> Safari -> Advanced)" mean?